# Find each 50,000, then next 50,000, etc. and save them in different files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have the following Rake file. Using RoR 2.3.8.

```
desc "Create shops sitemap"
task(:shops => :environment) do
  sitemap = Sitemap.new
  #add every item
  for i in shop.find(:all, :select => 'id, updated_at', :order => 'updated_at DESC', :limit => 50000)
    sitemap.add_url("http://abc.com/shops/#{i.id}",w3c_date(i.updated_at),'daily','1.0')
  end

  puts "#{sitemap.urls.length} total urls"
  #delete the file
  FileUtils.rm(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "public/sitemap_shops_1.xml.gz"), :force => true)

  f =File.new(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "public/sitemap_shops_1.xml"), 'w')

  sitemap.write(f,2)
  f.close

  system("gzip #{File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'public/sitemap_shops_1.xml')}")
end
```

The file above searches the first 50,000 records based on last updated, then save in a file numbered 1.

How do I modify the code to have it search the next 50,000, and save the file numbered 2, then next 50,000, save as file numbered 3, etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `find`, you can use `find_in_batches` which will return groups of 1,000 at a time (but you can override this to be 50,000 with the `:batch_size` option). Throw in a counter variable (since I don't think `find_in_batches` has anything like an `each_with_index`) and you can handle all the files you need.

```
desc "Create shops sitemap"
task(:shops => :environment) do
  file_name_index = 0
  Shop.find_in_batches(:all, :select => 'id, updated_at', :order => 'updated_at DESC', :batch_size => 50000) do |group_of_50000|
    file_name_index += 1
    sitemap = Sitemap.new
    #add every item
    for i in group_of_50000
      sitemap.add_url("http://abc.com/shops/#{i.id}",w3c_date(i.updated_at),'daily','1.0')
    end

    puts "#{sitemap.urls.length} total urls"
    #delete the file
    FileUtils.rm(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "public/sitemap_shops_#{file_name_index}.xml.gz"), :force => true)

    f =File.new(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "public/sitemap_shops_#{file_name_index}.xml"), 'w')

    sitemap.write(f,2)
    f.close

    system("gzip #{File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'public/sitemap_shops_#{file_name_index}.xml')}")
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I limit to only 4 groups (200,000)? Also, what happens if total record is only 150,000? Is it gonna return with error? Thanks!

Comment: You could probably throw in a `break if file_name_index == 4`, meaning it'll break if you just processed your 4th batch (200,000). Also, `find_in_batches` will handle any number of records. If you have 60,000 records, the first iteration will return 1-50,000, and the second iteration will return 50,001-60,000.

Comment: Thanks. After which line should I put the `break`?

Comment: This won't work as advertised, you can't set the order by clause on #find_in_batches. From the documentation: "It’s not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering work."